# How can I trigger a function using jQuery or JavaScript when the position of the component changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the two selectors below. When some more selectors are appended to *"render"*, the position of the *"comp1"* drops a little down and I want to execute a function every time there is a change in the position of *"comp1"*.

I've tried by binding to the change event, but it is not working as I want it to.

```
<div id="render" >
<div id="comp1" >
```

Here's the JS part I've tried:

```
function doUpdate(e){
    console.log("Component is updated "+e);
}
// capture change in the component
$('#comp1).bind('change', doUpdate);
```

Comment: Please provide more info and/or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example that shows the issue

Comment: `change` is for something completely different. It's hard to detect all cases when the position of something changes.

Answer (score 2):

The `change` event is fired when the input value of an input changes and the input loses focus. It won't be helpful here.

There's no special event that fires when some element changes its position relative to anything.

There are some of the events that can cause an element to reposition:

- The browser window is resized. This one is easy to detect.
- Some CSS or image is loaded. You could try hooking up to the `load` event of all styles and images. Not exactly lightweight.
- Some content is added to the page via Javascript. There are various DOM mutation events, but their support varies, and they have other disadvantages as well (namely, they fire much too often) and they are deprecated. Their replacement of mutation observers is not universally supported either, but at least they don't have the other disadvantages. Note that this may include other images and styles, so you'd need to hook their load events as well.
- CSS3 transitions and animations. There are events that fire when these start or end, but not in the middle.
- Javascript changes some style or CSS class. Mutation events detect attribute changes, but not property changes. At least some property changes don't affect the corresponding attribute. Look closely to the support table.
- The users resizes a textarea, or another element with the `resizable` CSS property set to anything but `resizable: none` (default for most elements). A workaround might be to disable resizing.

Without knowing the exact environment, it's next to impossible to get this right.

This leaves us with a last-resort option, polling for changes, but it has a several issues of its own: it doesn't pick up the changes immediately and uses the CPU even when nothing is changing (don't use for many elements!).

implemented as a jQuery plugin, it could look like:

```
(function($){
  var watches = $();
  var timeout = 100;
  var awake = false;
  $.fn.watcher = function(option, value){
    if(typeof option == 'function'){
      value = option;
      option = undefined;
    }
    switch(option){
      case 'watch':
      case undefined:
        watches = watches.add(this);
        if(typeof value == 'function'){
          this.on("watcher.move", value);
        }
        if(!awake && this.length > 0){
          awake = true;
          setTimeout(watcher, timeout);
        }
        break;
      case 'unwatch':
        watches = watches.not(this)
        break;
      case 'timeout':
        if(arguments.length == 1){
          return timeout;
        } else {
          timeout = value;
        }
      default: throw "unknown option "+option;
    }
    return this;
  }

  function watcher(){
    watches.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var oldPos = $this.data("watcher.position");
      var newPos = $this.offset(); //relative to the document
      if(oldPos && (oldPos.top !== newPos.top || oldPos.left !== newPos.left)){
        $this.trigger("watcher.move");
      }
      $this.data("watcher.position", newPos);
    })
    if(watches.length){
      setTimeout(watcher, timeout);
    } else {
      awake = false;
    }
  }
})(jQuery)
```

example usage:

```
$("#comp1")
  .watcher('timeout', 50)
  .watcher('watch')
  .on("watcher.move", function(){
    console.log("#comp1 has moved!")
  })
```

or just:

```
$("#comp1").watcher(function(){
  console.log("#comp1 has moved!")
})
```

tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/qC99z/

But, seriously, change your design so that you don't need this!!!